# Car makes grinding noise when starting, changed starter and battery, what is the problem?

Tags: noise, ignition, starter

At first my car would take a long time to start, then it would not start. The battery seemed fine since the car was getting power and would keep turning over with no success. So **I replaced the starter**. It worked twice, then I got this weird clicking noise. **I replaced the battery**, now the clicking noise is gone and the **car will start after it makes a horrible grinding noise.** 
I also thought the starter they sold me might have been defective, but I took it back to the store and they tested it, and said it was just fine.
When the car is running I do not have any problems.

Comment: The clicking was your solenoid because of the weak battery.

Comment: I'm guessing a bad starter drive gear.

Comment: What make and model of car is it? Some engines require shims for proper starter alignment to the flywheel. If it is not aligned properly, it can make grinding noises when starting the engine.

Comment: It is a 2007 Honda Accord. 4 Cylinder.